# Got error despite using either sklearn.cross_valid & sklearn.model_selection

Tags: python, scikit-learn

working on some beginner Machine Learning coder exercises. I'm stuck with an error with sklearn.cross_validation and sklearn.model_selection (neither works in my setup). Here's the log:

```
Python 2.7.12 (default, Dec  4 2017, 14:50:18) 
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
IPython 2.4.1 -- An enhanced Interactive Python.
?         -> Introduction and overview of IPython's features.
%quickref -> Quick reference.
help      -> Python's own help system.
object?   -> Details about 'object', use 'object??' for extra details.
%guiref   -> A brief reference about the graphical user interface.
In [1]: import numpy as np
   ...: import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
   ...: import pandas as pd
In [2]: dataset = pd.read_csv('Salary_Data.csv')
   ...: X = dataset.iloc[:, :-1].values
   ...: y = dataset.iloc[:, 1].values
In [3]: runfile('/home/rocketchef/Machine Learning/Machine Learning A-Z/Part 2 - Regression/Section 4 - Simple Linear Regression/simple_linear_regression.py', wdir='/home/rocketchef/Machine Learning/Machine Learning A-Z/Part 2 - Regression/Section 4 - Simple Linear Regression')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<ipython-input-3-2d267c940766>", line 1, in <module>
    runfile('/home/rocketchef/Machine Learning/Machine Learning A-Z/Part 2 - Regression/Section 4 - Simple Linear Regression/simple_linear_regression.py', wdir='/home/rocketchef/Machine Learning/Machine Learning A-Z/Part 2 - Regression/Section 4 - Simple Linear Regression')
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/spyderlib/widgets/externalshell/sitecustomize.py", line 699, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/spyderlib/widgets/externalshell/sitecustomize.py", line 81, in execfile
    builtins.execfile(filename, *where)
  File "/home/rocketchef/Machine Learning/Machine Learning A-Z/Part 2 - Regression/Section 4 - Simple Linear Regression/simple_linear_regression.py", line 14, in <module>
    from sklearn.cross_validation import train_test_split
ImportError: No module named sklearn.cross_validation
In [4]: from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
   ...: X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size = 1/3, random_state = 0)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<ipython-input-4-931d28d0dd1b>", line 1, in <module>
    from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
ImportError: No module named sklearn.model_selection
```

is it possible that the iPython 2.4 and Python 2.7 (as shown in the log)  I use in my Spyder 2.3.8 are the root of the issue? I tried to uninstall+reinstall and even update Spyder, but the program still shows the same versions and errors above.

Comment: what's the version of sklearn you're using?

Comment: Did you install sklearn?

Comment: @MedAli With `pip freeze | grep scikit-learn` at the terminal, i got this `scikit-learn==0.19.1`.

Comment: @Mufeed, hope this helps: When i checked within the iPythno console, i got this: `In [1]: import nltk
   ...: import sklearn
   ...: print('The nltk version is {}.'.format(nltk.__version__))
   ...: print('The scikit-learn version is {}.'.format(sklearn.__version__))
   ...: 
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-1-fb2a0e44f1c8>", line 1, in <module>
    import nltk

ImportError: No module named nltk`

Comment: as documented in (here)[http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split.html],  `from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split` should work. What's the message if you try to import sklearn?

Comment: @MedAli here, "ImportError": `from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size = 1/3, random_state = 0)
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-3-931d28d0dd1b>", line 1, in <module>
    from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

ImportError: No module named sklearn.model_selection
`

Comment: @RafaL try just `import sklearn`

Comment: @MedAli tried that one out as it is: `In [10]: from sklearn import train_test_split
    ...: X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size = 1/3, random_state = 0)
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-10-c8c8670e7485>", line 1, in <module>
    from sklearn import train_test_split

ImportError: No module named sklearn`

Comment: @RafaL sklearn isn't installed.. install it and try again